# Post picture to Tumblr using Python

Tags: python, tumblr

I'm trying to post a picture to tumblr, using python, in particular: http://code.google.com/p/python-tumblr/

#!/usr/bin/python

```
from tumblr import Api
import sys

BLOG='example.tumblr.com'
USER='example@example.com'
PASSWORD='example'
api = Api(BLOG,USER,PASSWORD)
post_data = "picture.png"   
title = "Title of my entry"
body = "this is a story with a picture"

api.write_regular(title, body + post_data)
```

When I run this the result is that the blog arrives, but instead of:

> Title of my entry
>
> this is a story with a picture
>
> [img]

I get this:

> Title of my entry
>
> this is a story with a
>   picturepicture.png

Comment: Maybe someone will write a proper answer, but I can at least tell your right now that you are sending 'picture.png' as a string, making it no different from "This is a story". Check the api docs for how to actually transfer an __image__

Comment: I dont think you need http://code.google.com/p/python-tumblr/. It just complicates the simple POST problem. Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3266194/image-uploading-from-python-or-curl-to-tumblr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your current code, you are not posting an image but you are sending a string which is called "picture.png". As Daniel DiPaolo said you have to use write a photo. The Argument for write_photo is the link to the image, for example.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from tumblr import Api
import sys

BLOG='example.tumblr.com'
USER='example@example.com'
PASSWORD='example'
api = Api(BLOG,USER,PASSWORD)
api.write_photo('http://example.org/somewhere/lolcat.jpg')
```

If you want to send HTML, you can create a body which is long containing the tags of your choices.

```
title = "life is amazing" 
body = """
_here my html code_
"""
```

Then write it with the API

```
api.write_regular(title,body)
```

and you should be all set.

### data upload

to be more precise ;) in the case you want to send data you have to open the object. 
Let's say your image is "lolcat.jpg"

data = open('lolcat.jpg').read()

Comment: The argument for `write_photo` is only the link to the image if you choose not to pass the image data in as the `data` arg :)

Answer (score 2):

You aren't actually sending the image data, you're just sending a string with the filename in it, so that's not too surprising.  The `write_regular` call [allows HTML](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api#api_write) so if you can upload the photo somewhere, you should be able to use an `<img src="..." />` tag in your post text to have the image displayed within your post.

Or you can use the [`write_photo`](http://code.google.com/p/python-tumblr/source/browse/trunk/tumblr.py#137) call to upload the photo (and not just the filename!) to Tumblr and then somehow get the URL to that and use that in your `<img>` tag for your post.

Comment: I figured so much, just didn't know how to change it to work :) Anyway, question slightly related: how can save a string which is html? As the markup of html obviously messes with Python.

Comment: How does HTML in a string mess with Python?  `'This is a cool picture: <img src="my_url_goes_here"/>'` works perfectly fine in Python (note you can use single quotes for strings if it's more convenient, which it might be in this case)

Comment: Ah that's probably why. I'm used to using double quotes.

Comment: You can also escape double quotes: `x = "< a href=\"\" />"`

Answer (score 1):

I made an example here with API v2 
https://gist.github.com/1242662