# Post picture from directory to tumblr via python

Tags: python, blogs, image, tumblr

I searched the boards and found a thread to which I used to make a script to upload a picture to tumblr.

```
from tumblr import Api
import sys

def antearaTumblr(blog, email, password):
    BLOG=blog
    USER=email
    PASSWORD=password
    api = Api(BLOG,USER,PASSWORD)
    #data = open('C:/Users/Kevin/Desktop/python-tumblr-0.1/1329360987775.jpg').read()
    api.write_photo('http://www.jonathanworthington.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2008/07/etc.jpg')
    title = ''
    body = ''
    api.write_regular(title,body)
```

This does work, it uses write_photo to grab a photo from the internet and upload it to my tumblr. However, I don't know how to make it grab a photo from a directory on my PC, like this....

```
from tumblr import Api
import sys

def antearaTumblr(blog, email, password):
    BLOG=blog
    USER=email
    PASSWORD=password
    api = Api(BLOG,USER,PASSWORD)
    data = open('C:/Users/Kevin/Desktop/python-tumblr-0.1/1329360987775.jpg').read()
    title = ''
    body = ''
    api.write_regular(title,data)
```

It succeeds in uploading, however all it uploads is this... ÿØÿà... which I assume is the jpg header.

I found this topic [Post picture to Tumblr using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938203/post-picture-to-tumblr-using-python) but I don't know exactly what the replies are saying.

Does anyone know how to get it to work using a directory and not a link?

Also, i tried this https://gist.github.com/1242662 but honestly I just had no idea how to do it.

Thanks for any help I receive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the linked post it seems that data is a keyword argument, so you'd call `api.write` like this:

```
api.write_regular(title, data=data)
```

I have no idea if that will work or not, but tumblr's API seems [well documented](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api#api_write). I would recommend using [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html) instead, which is by far the nicest HTTP library for Python. To upload a photo:

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.tumblr.com/api/write'
data = {'email': your_email, 'password': your_password, 'type': 'photo'}
files = {'data': open('your_image.jpg')}

requests.post(url, data=data, files=files)
```

Comment: Actually got it to work from the above link to github. Thanks.

Comment: Glad you got it working at least! I actually did test this before posting, and it worked fine for me. Perhaps you forgot to set email, password or change filename so it pointed to a real file? Doing nothing would be surprising, you could do `r = requests.post(...)` and look at `r.content` to see what error the service gave you.

Comment: I can't edit the previous post, but I am authenticated, as shown by when I purposely made a typo in my email it returned a different, wrong credentials error.

Comment: I've made a program using APIv2 however it requires a much longer authentication. I would prefer to do it with the method you described above. I can't upload a photo for some reason, however, I can upload a text post. I keep getting 'Error uploading photo', nomatter what photo it is.

Here is a pastebin describing what works and what doesn't work.
http://pastebin.com/9NE9PXkE

Any ideas?

Comment: You are calling `requests.post(url, data=data)` instead of `requests.post(url, data=data, files=files)`. You need to specify the files for the multi-part upload. Make sure you call `requests.post` like I do in my example.

Comment: I've actually tried to do data=data, files=files, however, I put files inside data for a reason that I will state in a second, I just want to let you know that i HAVE got this to work by reading the BINARY of the image, and then sending that to tumblr.
http://pastebin.com/rPSbaxUF
if you look above i get the user to input email and password, so i simply put the type and data in that same area to make it easier to read. However, as I am reading the binary data, according to tumblr API my max upload size is 5MB instead of 10MB. The way you do it would be 10MB.

Comment: Just to clarify, I did try `requests.post(url, data=data, files=files)`, that was the first thing I tried, yet it didn't work - in fact i tried exactly what you wrote in your answer, substituting 'your_image.jpg' for 'test.jpg' which was in the same folder as the .py file I am running the script from.

Comment: Edited your paste with proper way to make request as well as some other suggestions: http://pastebin.com/ejNaucJA.